# How to show 'hour precision' on datetimes in Plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I've looked-up answers on all blogs in vain ... I'm simply looking for a way to show datetimes with hour precision on my graphs. Here's an example of what my code generates :

My 'Start Date' & 'End Date' are normally on the following format 'mm-dd-yyyy H-M-S' however it won't show the hour precision until I zoom-in
[image]

I know the question sounds stupid, but if you can point me in the right direction I would be grateful

Edit :

[image]

Comment: Does the original data have time data? That and the data and code that the graph is based on should be shown.

Comment: Indeed, my original data does have time of course. Check the photo I added in Edit, once I zoom in they start showing me the date & time ... But when I auto-scale to see the whole interval they start clipping time from it even though it's not related to the length or something

Comment: For the X-Axis to be scaled the way that you want, you can refer to this: https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#using-tickformat-attribute--datetime and to get the exact formatting that you want, you can refer to this: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a case of setting **xaxis_tickformat**. without this sample below will behave as you described, no hour precision

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# for hour slots randonly assign a task
df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10**3, freq="4H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=1),
    Task=np.random.choice([f"Task {i}" for i in range(2)], 10**3, p=(0.8, 0.2)),
)

# compress consequetive rows
df = df.groupby(df.Task.ne(df.Task.shift()).cumsum()).agg(
    {"Start": "min", "End": "max", "Task": "first"})

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="End", y="Task", color="Task")

fig.update_layout(xaxis_tickformat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

#### change just hover template not overall axis

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="End", y="Task", color="Task")
print(fig.data[0].hovertemplate) # just FYI so can see what default template is
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="Task=%{y}<br>Start=%{base|%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}<br>End=%{x|%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}<extra></extra>")
```

Comment: I truly appreciate responses like these. It is brief, simple & constructive. Thanks a lot Rob for your time !

Comment: Can't help but notice that your method applies the same format for the plotted data & the x axis as well. Wouldn't there be a way to keep the x axis intact and modify the format of the data only ? I tried modifying the dataframe (that contains the plotted data) and it was in vain

Comment: it's really just the same techniques... have updated how to just change the **hover** text